# Regular expression for 3 decimal with min and max value

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Please i need help to optimize the input filter on my customEditText

Requirement:

```
min float = 0.001
max float = 1000.000
decimal number = 3
```

I want to avoid 0 from the user set but he can enter something like 0.01 , 0.001 , 1.555 and 1000.000

This is what i've tested so far:

I used this function to set the min and max

```kotlin
    class EditTextInputFilter(min: Float, max: Float) : InputFilter {
        private val min: Float = min.coerceAtMost(max)
        private val max: Float = min.coerceAtLeast(max)

        override fun filter(source: CharSequence, i: Int, i2: Int, spanned: Spanned, i3: Int, i4: Int): CharSequence? {
            try {
                val input = (spanned.toString() + source.toString()).toFloatOrZero()
                if (isInRange(min, max, input)) {
                    return null
                }
            } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
                Logger.error(nfe.localizedMessage!!)
            }
            return ""
        }

        private fun isInRange(min: Float, max: Float, value: Float): Boolean {
            return value in min..max
        }
    }
```

I used this Decimal filter to remove comment and un-useful dots

```kotlin
    class DecimalFilter(private val decimalDigits: Int) : InputFilter {
            override fun filter(source: CharSequence, i: Int, i2: Int, spanned: Spanned, i3: Int, i4: Int): CharSequence? {
                var dotPos = -1
                val len = spanned.length
                for (decimalsI in 0 until len) {
                    val c = spanned[decimalsI]
                    if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
                        dotPos = decimalsI
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (dotPos >= 0) {
                    // protects against many dots
                    if (source == "." || source == ",") return ""
                    // if the text is entered before the dot
                    if (i4 <= dotPos) return null
                    if (len - dotPos > decimalDigits) return ""
                }
                return null
            }
        }

    
      class CustomEditText : TextInputEditText {

        private var decimals = 3
        private var min = 0.001f
        private var max = 1000f

        private lateinit var oldFilters: MutableList<InputFilter>

        constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
            init(null)
        }

        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {
            init(attrs)
        }

        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context!!, attrs, defStyle) {
            init(attrs)
        }

        private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
            isInEditMode
            if (attrs != null) {
                val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText, 0, 0)
                decimals = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_decimals, decimals)
                min = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomEditText_min, min)
                max = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomEditText_max, max)
            }
            oldFilters = filters.toMutableList()
            addFilters()
        }

        private fun addFilters() {
            val inputFilters = ArrayList<InputFilter>(oldFilters.size + 1)
            inputFilters.addAll(oldFilters)
            inputFilters.add(EditTextInputFilter(min, max))
            inputFilters.add(DecimalFilter(decimals))
            filters = inputFilters.toTypedArray()
        }

        fun setMin(min: Float) {
            this.min = min
            addFilters()
        }

        fun setMax(max: Float) {
            this.max = max
            addFilters()
        }

        fun setDecimals(decimals: Int) {
            this.decimals = decimals
            addFilters()
        }
    }
```

My problem now is, i can not enter 0

Comment: what have you tried so far? also why use regex? also I would recommend not to have a free text field but use a masked input field, there are plenty of libs out there like https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: Sounds like a simple range check would do, I deleted my answer since I haven't seen any effort on your side yet to solve it

Comment: Hi, @EmanuelMoecklin thanks for your reply. i was trying this

(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin you have not seen any effort cause i was testing some solution

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are the right answer to this problem.

Comment: @K.Donon it's good practice on SO to show what you tried. SO isn't meant to have other people do your work but to get unstuck if you're stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin i know but i taught the code is too much to enter that is why but i edited my post again.

Comment: @K.Donon thanks for posting the code, now it's clear what your problem is, before posting the code the question wasn't clear so it's important to give the context to be able to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EmanuelMoecklin After reading your proposal answer i reviewed my code with this code below and it works perfectly and also i can re-use it for other input field.

I use my EditTextInputFilter class to set the min and max. The DecimalFilter class to set the number of decimal

```
class EditTextInputFilter(min: Float, max: Float) : InputFilter {
    private val min: Float = min.coerceAtMost(max)
    private val max: Float = min.coerceAtLeast(max)

    override fun filter(source: CharSequence, i: Int, i2: Int, spanned: Spanned, i3: Int, i4: Int): CharSequence? {
        try {
            val input = (spanned.toString() + source.toString()).toFloatOrZero()
            if (isInRange(min, max, input)) {
                return null
            }
        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
            Logger.error(nfe.localizedMessage!!)
        }
        return ""
    }

    private fun isInRange(min: Float, max: Float, value: Float): Boolean {
        return value in min..max
    }
 }

class DecimalFilter(private val decimalDigits: Int) : InputFilter {
     override fun filter(source: CharSequence, i: Int, i2: Int, spanned: Spanned, i3: Int, i4: Int): CharSequence? {
    var dotPos = -1
    val len = spanned.length
    for (decimalsI in 0 until len) {
        val c = spanned[decimalsI]
        if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
            dotPos = decimalsI
            break
        }
    }
    if (dotPos >= 0) {
        // protects against many dots
        if (source == "." || source == ",") return ""
        // if the text is entered before the dot
        if (i4 <= dotPos) return null
        if (len - dotPos > decimalDigits) return ""
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

I've created another validate function :

```
private fun validateInput(input: String): Boolean {
  val double = input.toDoubleOrNull()
  return double != null && double in 0.001f...1000f
}
```

Than i set the input filter like this on my input field:

```kotlin
binding.valueTiet.filters = arrayOf(EditTextInputFilter(0f, 1000f), DecimalFilter(3))
binding.valueTiet.doAfterTextChanged {
    if (validateInput(it)) {
        binding.valueTietTil.error = ""
        Logger.info("Value accepted")
    } else {
        binding.valueTietTil.error = "Allowed range [0.001-1000]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're validating the field as the user types and since the range of allowed values is 0.001..1000.000 you cannot type the number 0 (even if the intention is to enter 0.1).
This is not a coding but a specification problem.

The way it's specified is:

- don't accept values outside 0.001..1000.000
- validate as the user types

It's impossible to meet these requirements. I see a couple of solutions:

- validate once the user submits (not as the user types)
- validate without blocking the user input (by using `setError` in a `TextWatcher`)
  [image: List item]
- allow 0 values in your filter (range 0..1000.000) but add another validation when the user submits to eliminate the 0
- allow 0 values in your filter (range 0..1000.000) and disable the submit button (or whatever you have to process the input) if the value isn't in range

From a ux perspective I'd vote for the last option and maybe also indicate to the user what values are allowed so they know why they can't continue